# how to run NVIDIA Deepstream6.2 sample

Tags: nvidia

"I want to execute tracking as shown in the blog link below using NVIDIA DeepStream 6.2 sample. Can you tell me how?

Blog Link: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/state-of-the-art-real-time-multi-object-trackers-with-nvidia-deepstream-sdk-6-2/

My setup environment is as follows:

1. OS: Ubuntu 20.04
2. CUDA: 12.2
3. Driver Version: 535.86.10
4. Using Docker

I followed the README and utilized the files under "/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream/samples/configs/deepstream-app" subdirectory.
I executed the command below from this location. However, I encountered an error.

Command:
`deepstream-app -c source30_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tiled_display_int8.txt --gst-debug-level=3`

```
The error message is as follows:
0:00:00.058576017 1486 0x5603dd6cc030 ERROR egladaption ext/eglgles/gstegladaptation_egl.c:160:gst_egl_adaptation_init_display:<sink_sub_bin_sink1> Could not...
0:00:00.058601065 1486 0x5603dd6cc030 ERROR egladaption ext/eglgles/gstegladaptation_egl.c:183:gst_egl_adaptation_init_display:<sink_sub_bin_sink1> EGL call...
0:00:00.058604251 1486 0x5603dd6cc030 ERROR egladaption ext/eglgles/gstegladaptation_egl.c:185:gst_egl_adaptation_init_display:<sink_sub_bin_sink1> Couldn't...
0:00:00.058606515 1486 0x5603dd6cc030 ERROR nveglglessink ext/eglgles/gsteglglessink.c:537:egl_init:<sink_sub_bin_sink1> Couldn't init EGL display...
0:00:00.058608790 1486 0x5603dd6cc030 ERROR nveglglessink ext/eglgles/gsteglglessink.c:563:egl_init:<sink_sub_bin_sink1> Failed to perform EGL init...
** ERROR: main:716: Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED
Quitting
nvstreammux: Successfully handled EOS for source_id=0
App run failed."
```

How can I run DeepStream6.2 sample???